# Java system level deployment.properties

Tags: java, config, java-web-start

Since 7u10, Java show new "out of date" warning if not using newest jre version. Java updates have been cause problems for our Java Web Start application. We want test our application with new update before we can say to our customers that its ok to update Java. I have trying to block new "out of date" warning in system level with no results. I have created two files deployment.config and deployment.properties in path C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\Deployment\ but looks like nothing works.

deployment.config-file:

```
deployment.system.config=file\:C\:/WINDOWS/Sun/Java/Deployment/deployment.properties
deployment.system.config.mandatory=true
```

deployment.properties-file:

```
deployment.javaws.autodownload=NEVER
deployment.expiration.check.enabled=false
```

[Oracle Deployment Configuration File and Properties doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/properties.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> deployment.system.config is the URL to the system (enterprise-wide)
>   deployment.properties file. This property can be used by system
>   administrators to centrally administer or "lock-down" user-specific
>   configuration settings. For local files, use the file protocol in the
>   URL, for example,
>   file:///C:/Windows/Sun/Java/Deployment/deployment.properties.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/jcp/properties.html

Note the forward slashes (I had this issue before).

Comment: The reason that the forward slashes are needed is because the property is expecting a file URI.  See Wikipedia's [File_URI_scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) page for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This deployment.expiration.check.enabled=false property works only starting from Java 7 Update 40
Which version are you testing ?

Comment: i use Java 7 Update 40

Answer (score -1):

Your folder path is wrong - C\:/WINDOWS/Sun/Java/Deployment/deployment.properties

Try C:\Windows\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties